# Unable to run Appium tests on iOS using autoAcceptAlerts

Tags: c#, ios, appium, ios-ui-automation, ui-testing

I'm using Appium 1.3.6 on Mac OS X, and writing my tests in C#.
I've added **autoAcceptAlerts** capability parameter to my test init, so it looks like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Appium server...");
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "iOS");
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Mac 10.10");
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, version);
capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", device);
capabilities.SetCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);

driver = new IOSDriver(new Uri("my-appium-URL"), capabilities);

Console.WriteLine("Connection established.");
```

And after adding it, I can only successfully launch test only occasionally. Most of the time I see app is launched, alert is closed, main activity shows, but then test fails. What I see in the logs is:

```
Given I start app for iOS 8.1 on iPad Retina
Connecting to Appium server...
-> error: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL <my-appium-URL> timed out after 60 seconds.
```

And from Appium log:

```
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:39 +0000 Debug: target.frontMostApp().alert().buttons()[1].tap()
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:40 +0000 Debug: Waiting for alert to close...
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:40 +0000 Debug: Waiting for alert to close...
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:41 +0000 Debug: Got new command 1 from instruments: au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:41 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.setScreenOrientation('PORTRAIT')
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:41 +0000 Debug: target.setDeviceOrientation("1")
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:42 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:42 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:42 +0000 Debug: Running system command #2: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}...
info: [debug] Socket data received (33 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":"PORTRAIT"}
info: [debug] Waiting for app source to contain elements
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:43 +0000 Debug: Got new command 2 from instruments: au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
info: [debug] [INST] 2015-03-23 22:29:43 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.6","revision":"004f52f249d3513809e7d0734d9205d1fec19f8e"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"86e71593-3f35-4cbb-a7d4-a53b0eb38a4d"}
```

So, *au.mainApp().getTreeForXML()* is not being evaluated in time. If I remove **autoAcceptAlerts** parameter from init, I need to close alert manually, but evaluation happens just after a second or so, and test runs fine.

Maybe someone stumbled upon similar problem and has some kind of insight about what's going on? Would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite some time of trial and errors I replaced

```
capabilities.SetCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
driver = new IOSDriver(new Uri("my-appium-URL"), capabilities);
```

with

```
driver = new IOSDriver(new Uri("my-appium-URL"), capabilities);
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

And everything works fine. Still, it would be nice to know why **autoAcceptAlerts** causes this problem, but for now I'm pretty happy.